# how to use the get the item choosen through the id

Tags: php, get

How can I add a $_get method to this code, and make it appear as "this is a apple in another page"

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 post">
<a href="fruit.php?id=1"> <img src="image/apple.jpg"></a> <h4> apple</h4>
 </div>
```

How can I add a $_get method to this code, and make it appear as "this is a orange in another page"

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 post">
                <a href="fruit.php?id=2">
                    <img src="image/orange.jpg"></a>
                <h4>orange</h4>
        </div>
```

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: how can a use $_get in the above code, which will help me to get the result of the item that I have chosen in the next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `fruit.php` page you can do like below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    if($_GET["id"]==1)
    {
        echo "This is an apple in another page";
    }
    else if($_GET["id"]==2)
    {
        echo "This is an orange in another page";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was really helpful

Comment: If you find this answer useful please mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    if($_GET["id"]==1)
    {
        echo "This is an apple";
    }
    else if($_GET["id"]==2)
    {
        echo "This is an orange";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was really helpful (Perfect):)

Answer (score -1):

You can use query strings (`fruit.php?id=1&fruit_name=apple` OR `fruit.php?id=1&fruit_name=orange`)

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 post">
  <a href="fruit.php?id=1&fruit_name=apple"><img src="image/apple.jpg"></a><h4> apple</h4>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 post">
  <a href="fruit.php?id=2&fruit_name=orange"><img src="image/orange.jpg"></a><h4> Orange</h4>
</div>
```

In the page `fruit.php`, you can get the fruit name as follows

```
<?php if( isset($_GET['fruit_name']) ){ echo 'This is an '.$_GET['fruit_name']; } ?>
```

Comment: If you already know id 1 is apple why do you need to send it again? Isn't it redundant?

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was really helpful